# Run-time error; method is not a member of the given namespace

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I run my application to test it, I navigate to the page and get this error:

```
BC30456: 'CheckUserStatus' is not a member of 'UDPC'.
<%If UD.UDPC.CheckUserStatus(aIsPopup, "UDCMain.aspx", aReason) = False Then%>
```

But if I use `Go To Definition` on `CheckUserStatus` in Visual Studio it takes me to the declaration for this method, in another class in the same project, which is defined as such:

```
Public Function CheckUserStatus(ByVal aIsPopup As Boolean, ByVal aFrom As String, ByRef aReason As String)

    Return mCheckUserStatus(aIsPopup, aFrom, aReason)

End Function
```

`mCheckUserStatus` is defined as such, in the same class as the previous method:

```
Public Function mCheckUserStatus(ByVal aIsPopup As Boolean, Optional ByVal aFrom As String = "", Optional ByRef aReason As String = "") As Boolean
     // a bunch of logic to determine if mCheckUserStatus = true or false
End Function
```

I'm new to VB, but I have a decent bit of C# experience but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong here.

Also something that I don't understand, how is `CheckUserStatus` able to `return mCheckUserStatus(...)` when `As Boolean` isn't appended to the method declaration?

**edit**; I think I just found it. `CheckUserStatus` is part of `Public Module UDRequest` but `mCheckUSerStatus` is part of `Module UDCommonLocal` -- not a Public module ?

**edit2**; I tried to fully qualify it by changing it to `<% If ...UDRequest.CheckUserStatus...` but that didn't change anything, either.

Comment: Make that function shared... otherwise you need an instance of that class. Also turn on Option Strict youll see why.

Comment: @436f6465786572 `Methods in a module cannot be shared` is what I get if I try that.

Comment: Is it a public module?

Comment: @436f6465786572 I believe it's private, since it doesn't specify an access modifier.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, I would try to import the namespace, something like:

`<%@ Import Namespace="YourNamespace" %>`

For you 2nd question - Vb.net knows how to convert the type. It's like returning a generic object in C#.

If you convert your code using a C# to Vb.net [code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) you'd get:

```
public object CheckUserStatus(bool aIsPopup, string aFrom, ref string aReason)
{
    return mCheckUserStatus(aIsPopup, aFrom, aReason);
}
```

Comment: I tried adding an Import for `UDCommonLocal` as mentioned in my edit, in the actual code behind for the ASP file, and separately in the ASP file itself as you had suggested but unfortunately this did not fix the problem- same results

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a very bizarre issue with some local permissions on some files in Windows and build configurations in Visual Studio- nothing really code related that anyone here would have been able to help with.